# Android status bar expects icons of size 25x25dp while guidelines recommend 32x32dp. Who is wrong?

Tags: android, size, android-icons

According to android icon design guidelines ([here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html), see table #1), developer needs to provide status bar icons of next sizes:

```
Status Bar  24 x 24 px (LDPI)  32 x 32 px (MDPI)  48 x 48 px (HDPI)
```

While my measurements show that status bar always has 25 dp in height and expects icons of 25x25dp. This translates to these sizes:

```
Status Bar  19 x 19 px (LDPI) 25 x 25 px (MDPI)  38 x 38 px (HDPI)
```

Here is how I get those size:

```
25dp * 0.75 = 18.75 => 19px (LDPI)
25dp *  1   = 25    => 25px (MDPI)
25dp *  1.5 = 37.5  => 38px (HDPI)
```

I have confirmed calculated sizes on several Android phones and on emulators.

The question basically is: why guidelines use sizes different from what is really used by status bar?

P.S. I actually need to break guidelines due to precise pixel control requirements. And I just was confused by this state of affairs. So explanation of why this the way it is would really help me.

Comment: No idea why the doc is wrong. Maybe it was correct long ago before a Google designer decided to knock 7 pixels off the status bar's height. Certainly the status bar icons in the SDK's android.jar are 25px for MDPI and 38px for HDPI, so your observations look 100% correct to me.

Comment: I think that is just copy/paste error cause in chapter Status bar icon (http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html#statusbarstructure) 25x25 size spesified.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**Warning: regardless of whether or not the answer was correct when written, it appears not to be correct now. See https://www.google.com/design/spec/style/icons.html for the current guidelines.**

It just seems to be an error. (Note that as of 2010-12-04, they've also crossed their references to figures 4 and 5 on that page.)

As Lex points out, they have the correct number further down, in the ["Status bar icon" section](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design.html#statusbarstructure).

They also dictate a 2-pixel "safeframe" on all sides at 25x25 which the shape of your icon must fit within, though it seems that it is okay to have some aliasing-related stuff stick out, but **only on the sides**, for this type of icon. (Meaning that you really want to aim for 21x21 at that size.)

Comment: Please note that dp units mentioned on Android website are not pixels. See https://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html for details on how dp translates to pixels. So 24x24 dp are **not** always 24x24 pixels and in this answer instead of pixels, dp should be mentioned.

Comment: Android website has since been updated and no longer references pixel dimensions of the 24dp icons, if you're looking here for exact export values. You can use a web tool like https://pixplicity.com/dp-px-converter/ to calculate them for you, or see the answer below.

Answer (score 55):

Actually it's

- 18px(ldpi)
- 24px(mdpi)
- 36px(hdpi)
- 48px(xhdpi)
- 72px(xxhdpi)
- 96px(xxxhdpi)

it's 24dp size with a 2dp padding , means 20dp content

px = dp * (dpi/160)

Comment: xxhdpi should be 72x72

Comment: 24dp minus 2dp padding is actually 20dp (padding goes for all sides).

Comment: and xxxhdpi at 96x96px

Comment: and xxxxhdpi at I hope they don't keep making devices with stupid high resolutions for marketing reasons

Comment: Where did you get these numbers from?

Comment: Android Lint: Incorrect icon size for `drawable-mdpi`\ic_stat_launcher.png: icon size should be at most `16x25`, but was `24x24`