# Android Status Bar Icon Size - Using Cordova / Phonegap Push Plugin

Tags: android, cordova, push-notification, ionic-framework, phonegap-pushplugin

Im developing an Android app using Ionic (Cordova + AngularJS). With it i use the Push Plugin (https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin)

In my resources Folder i have 6 different Application Icons specified, from `ldpi` to `xxxhdpi`

```
<icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" density="ldpi"/>
<icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" density="mdpi"/>
<icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" density="hdpi"/>
<icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" density="xhdpi"/>
<icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxhdpi"/>
<icon src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" density="xxxhdpi"/>
```

Now after i build this, my final resources folder structure looks something like this:

```
android/res/drawable-ldpi/icon.png
android/res/drawable-mdpi/icon.png
```

and so on...

Now this works perfectly fine for the App icon on all devices. 
But if i get a Push Notification, the app icon appearing in the status bar is too big, so only the middle of the icon is displayed (only for the first seconds, seems there is a reload of the notification after that (if i pull down the status bar for example) it is displayed correctly).

After a bit of research i found that the icons i provided are correct for the general app icons, but icons for the status bar have to be in another dimension as i found out here: [Android status bar expects icons of size 25x25dp while guidelines recommend 32x32dp. Who is wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4265595/android-status-bar-expects-icons-of-size-25x25dp-while-guidelines-recommend-32x3) (2nd answer)

For example, using my Samsung s5 i switched out my xxhdpi icon of 144*144px for the same icon in 72*72px size and it works. the icon is not cut anymore.

---

**Now to my question:**
How do i have to setup this "secondary" icons which i use for the notifications only in my resources folder without overwriting the original ones?

Comment: Did you try to generate all your icons with the generator provided by the ionic team? http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/icon-splashscreen.html

Comment: actually i didnt. thanks for the hint, will try it out.

Comment: Doesn't make a difference. Icon is still broken on push notification (when its received the first time..)

Comment: @Kryptik did you solve this?

Comment: nope. not trying at the moment, but didn't find a solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to be so stricted about the image size. Put two icons in the platform/android/res/drawable folder. One to show on navigation bar on lollipop (eg.: small_icon.png), it needs to be white and with no background. And other one to older android versions (eg.: large_icon.png).

Open the PushPlugin config file located at:

```
platforms/android/src/com/plugin/gcm/GCMIntentService.java
```

Set your icons path in the NotificationCompat.Builder object:

```
.setSmallIcon(com.domain.appName.R.drawable.small_icon)
.setLargeIcon(largeIcon)
```

The large icon needs to be a bitmap, so define before that:

```
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;

Bitmap largeIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), com.domain.appName.R.drawable.large_icon);
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks, actually very helpful for me, but not for this case. Adding the LargeIcon only makes a difference for me on Lollipop after i pulled down the statusbar (to see the notification details). There i have now the large Icon with a (100% white) small icon on the lower right side of the large icon. But the problem on the statusbar still remains.